# Need to make a simple spring 3 example work

Tags: eclipse, spring

I am learning spring 3 from a book and I get an exception in the first example itself. It is given below. 
My project can be downloaded as a zip file from the link - https://github.com/double-whammy/prospring3.git

My environment - Eclipse STS (Eclipse for Spring)

Exception:

```
INFO t.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext: 456 - Refreshing org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@497e4b: startup date [Wed Jul 23 10:05:47 PDT 2014]; 
root of context hierarchy
INFO eans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader: 315 - Loading XML bean definitions from class path resource [META-INF/spring/app-context.xml]

Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 13 in XML document from class path resource [META-INF/spring/app-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 13; columnNumber: 38; The prefix "p" for attribute "p:messageProvider-ref" associated with an element type "bean" is not bound.
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:396)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:334)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:126)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractXmlApplicationContext.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractXmlApplicationContext.java:92)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.refreshBeanFactory(AbstractRefreshableApplicationContext.java:130)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.obtainFreshBeanFactory(AbstractApplicationContext.java:467)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:397)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at com.apress.prospring3.ch2.HelloWorldSpringDI.main(HelloWorldSpringDI.java:9)
Caused by: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 13; columnNumber: 38; The prefix "p" for attribute "p:messageProvider-ref" associated with an element type "bean" is not bound.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultDocumentLoader.loadDocument(DefaultDocumentLoader.java:75)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:388)
    ... 14 more
```

Spring XML Application Configuration xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance 
xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p" 
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd"> 
<bean id="provider" class="com.apress.prospring3.ch2.HelloWorldMessageProvider"/> 
<bean id="renderer" class="com.apress.prospring3.ch2.StandardOutMessageRenderer" 
p:messageProvider-ref="provider"/> 
</beans>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because your xml is a invalid:

the header has a mistake: there the `xsi` attribute value needs its double quotes!

```
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
```

---

<strike>`<bean id="renderer" class="com.apress.prospring3.ch2.StandardOutMessageRenderer"
          p:messageProvider-ref="provider"/>`</strike>

<strike>I do not know what you want to configure, but a  `p:messageProvider-ref` as an attribute is invalid xml.</strike>

<strike>I thing you wanted to express something like a bean `renderer` of type `StandardOutMessageRenderer` that use the bean `provider` for its `MessageProvider`.</strike>

<strike>`<bean id="provider" class="com.apress.prospring3.ch2.HelloWorldMessageProvider"/> <bean id="renderer" class="com.apress.prospring3.ch2.StandardOutMessageRenderer"><property name="messageProvider"  ref="provider"/></bean>`</strike>

Comment: I thought so too, but then I did a quick google search and it looks like it's legit

Comment: @dimoniy: I posted how I would write it

Comment: I made the changes youu suggested. New exception is - `Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 3 in XML document from class path resource [META-INF/spring/app-context.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 3; columnNumber: 12; Open quote is expected for attribute "{1}" associated with an  element type  "xmlns:xsi".
`

Comment: `<bean id="renderer" class="com.apress.prospring3.ch2.StandardOutMessageRenderer"
      p:messageProvider-ref="provider"/> ` Is invalid ? so, my book is wrong in the opening chapter itself.

Comment: @james: found - the SAX Parser is right, line 3 is the problem

Answer (score 1):

You can not use: `p:messageProvider-ref="provider"`, it was in spring 2.5

use this:

```
<bean id="renderer" class="com.appress.prospring3.ch2.StandardOutMessageRenderer">      
        <property name="messageProvider" ref="provider"></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because there are no quotes around the value of xmlns:xsi.
Correction - xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
Pro spring 3 book sucks.

full xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">
    <bean id="provider" class="com.apress.prospring3.ch2.HelloWorldMessageProvider" />
    <bean id="renderer" class="com.apress.prospring3.ch2.StandardOutMessageRenderer"
        p:messageProvider-ref="provider" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you have is related to the fact that maven only picks one of the spring.handlers files from all the different spring jars.

To solve this use the following link:
http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/examples/resource-transformers.html#Merging_Content_of_Specific_Files_with_AppendingTransformer_and_XmlAppendingTransformer

Note that you have to use the maven Assembly Plugin.

Similar problems as yours are explained here:
http://blog.idm.fr/2009/09/maven-assembly-plugin-and-spring-namespace-handlers.html